# Determine the Size of a Network Folder

Tags: powershell, shared-folders

I want a PowerShell script to get the size of a network folder (`\\pmintl.net\rbsdata\SPA_BB01`) approximately 100TB in size with lots of subfolders.

I've tried various scripts without any luck (below is an example of one I tried but this appeared to hang):

```
$startFolder = "\\pmintl.net\rbsdata\SPA_BB01"
"Folder use {0:0,0.00} MB" -f ((Get-ChildItem -R $startFolder | measure-object length -Sum).Sum / 1TB)
```

Comment: What results are you getting when you run your script as-s?

Comment: no result it is running for long and I have to kill it.

Comment: If I run it against a share here it completes in a few seconds. How long is the "Long" time you let it run for?  How many folders and files are in that shared folder?  How fast is your connection to that share?

Comment: no result after 30 mints so i killed but in my shared folder there are lots of sub folder also

Comment: Try it without the "-R" and see if it finishes.  Then/also try the command `Get-ChildItem -R "\\pmintl.net\rbsdata\SPA_BB01"` by itself and see if it finishes, and how long it takes. If you have thousands of folders with thousands of files in them then it may take quite a while, especially if you're on a slow connection.  Another thing to try is running it on the server directly, and compare times.

Comment: It is not working with -r anyway i am trying the below script and currently it is running since 15 mints but no result $directory = "\\pmintl.net\rbsdata\SPA_BB01"


 write-host "- $directory" -foreground "GREEN"
  [string]$result = robocopy /b /l /mir "$directory" "c:\whatever" /r:0 /w:0 /ns /nc /nfl /ndl /njh /bytes
  if (!($lastexitcode -eq 16))
  {
    $pos = ($result).indexof("Bytes : ")
    $start = $pos + 8
    $length = $result.length
    $end = $length - $start
    $newstring = ($result).substring($start,$end)
    $newstring = $newstring.trim()
    echo $newstring.split()[0]
  }

Comment: If there are millions of files it will probably take anything much longer than 30 minutes.  How many files are there in your estimation?

Answer (score 2):

Below are two PowerShell scripts, the first one obtains the overall folder amount and the second one provides a breakdown of each subfolder (bear in mind if the folder is HUGE, this may take some time to obtain)...

Folder:

```
$colItems = (Get-ChildItem "\\pmintl.net\rbsdata\SPA_BB01" -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
"{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
```

Folder including subfolders:

```
$startFolder = "\\pmintl.net\rbsdata\SPA_BB01"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
"$startFolder -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | Sort-Object)
foreach ($i in $colItems)
    {
        $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
        $i.FullName + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
    }
```

You may want to check this TechNet article out which explains further including going into more depth regarding the properties/additional information which can be obtained.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730945.aspx